# How to find sum of each 2 numbers in an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

What I am trying to do is to print the sum of each two numbers in an array 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
int n;
cin>>n;
int arr[n*2];
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i<n*2 ; i++)
{
    count++;
    cin>>arr[i];
    if (count%2==0)
    {
        sum+=arr[i];


    }

    }
for (int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++)
    cout<<sum<<endl;
}
```

Why does this code print the sum of the whole array not each 2 elements in the array? 
for example I want to print some of arr[0] + arr[1] , arr[2] + arr[3] , arr[4] + arr[5] etc. each two numbers in a line. So How can I do that?

Comment: Look at `if (count%2==0)` and think about the value of `count` for a while.

Comment: Also, there's only one `sum=0` outside the loop. If you want n/2 sums¸ you'll have to clear it n/2 times.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @Adam Hussein  It is unclear what you want. Do you want to get the sum of all numbers that are at even positions in an array?

Comment: You're now summing half the array and then printing that sum `n` times. Read the entire array first. Then iterate over it and print the pairwise sums.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow No, I want to sum each 2 elements in the array for example array elements are 7 1 5 4 3 2 7 5 so it prints 8 9 5 12

Comment: What happens if the user enters the letter 'A' for the input? why do you have the 'count' variable at all...whats wrong with using the 'i' variable, which would more appropriately be named 'index'? Why are you adding the sum of two numbers to the previous sum? Is that what you described in your requirements? Why do you have a second loop? What is that loop doing? Could you do it in the first? All these questions and more will bring you to your answer.

Comment: BTW, the expression `int arr[n*2];` is not standard C++.  It is Variable Length Array (VLA) and maybe an extension to your compiler.  Prefer `std::vector` or dynamically allocate with `operator new`.

Comment: `cin>>n;
int arr[n*2];` is not valid C++. VLA is an extension. use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Do you really need to use an array?  You can sum numbers without storing all of them into an array.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Consider it's valid because it runs fine on codeblocks without an error, Have you got my question?

Comment: Try something simpler first. Assign values to all of the element of the array, then try to print them all out. *Then* try to print sums.

Comment: @Beta ... as it is shown in my answer.:)

Comment: *Consider it's valid because it runs fine on codeblocks without an error* -- 

I wish g++ or whatever compiler would turn **off** the setting to allow Variable Length Arrays, and only have the programmer enable the setting (thus only programmers who know about it and know exactly that it isn't standard C++ will make use of it). There are too many beginners in C++ being led down the wrong track by using things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an array.  You can save the previous value.

```
int previous = 0;
int present  = 0;
unsigned int quantity;
cin >> quantity;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
{
  cin >> present;
  const int sum = previous + present;
  cout << sum << "\n";
  previous = present;
}
```

The above code fragment uses the variable `previous` to store the previous number that was input.

Since the sum is only of the previous and present, there is no need for an entire array or `std::vector`.

Output:

```
6  // Quantity
4  // First number 
4  // Sum: first number + 0, since there is no previous.
5  // Input number 2
9  // Sum: previous (4) + present (5).
6
11
7
13
20
27
8
28
```

**Edit 1: Using an array**
The following example uses an array:
unsigned int quantity = 0;

```
cin >> quantity;
int * p_array = new int [quantity];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
{
  cin >> p_array[i];
}
for (unsigned int i = 1; i < quantity; ++i)
{
  const int sum = p_array[i] + p[i - 1];
  cout << sum << "\n";
}
delete [] p_array;
```

Yes, this can be done with one pass, but if you want efficiency, use the first example.

Comment: Well, when I enter 6 as the size of the loop and start to enter numbers for example I enter 4 5 the supposed answer is 9, with your code it prints 49.

Comment: Try again, I added a newline after every sum.

Comment: Why does it print the previous and the sum separated with a line?

Comment: The first example can be edited to skip the first printing of the sum.

Answer (score 0):

As it was already pointed out in the comments the C++ Standard does not have such a feature as variable length arrays.

So you should either declare an array of a fixed size or use for example standard container `std::vector`.

If an array is already declared and filled with values then the corresponding loop that outputs the sums can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 7, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 5 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N;  )
    {
        long long int sum = a[i++];
        if ( i != N ) sum += a[i++];

        std::cout << sum << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
8 9 5 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short solution using the [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) function and using a value to increment by in the container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    int incValue = 2;

    // assume number of data is evenly divisible by incValue
    std::vector<int> arr = { 7, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 5 };  

    // add incValue items at a time in a loop, and output results each iteration
    for ( auto startIter = arr.begin(); startIter != arr.end(); startIter += incValue)
        std::cout << std::accumulate(startIter, startIter + incValue, 0) << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
8 9 5 12
```